# Is there a study that supports the claim that sexual deprivation leads to sexual deviancy?

Tags: sexuality

Can anyone give studies that, if they exist, prove that sexual deprivation leads to sexual deviancy in later stages of life?

Comment: I mean becoming interested in more obscure types of sexual activity (pedophilia, zoophilia, violence, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

*Personality Theories*
Seidman and colleagues(1994) examined loneliness/intimacy problems regarding sexual offenders which suggested lack of social skills created intimacy problems

Bowlby (1988) which suggested people may take part in forms of sexual abuse as a result of loneliness/isolation which sexual deprivation is a by-product of

*Cognitive Theories*
(Scott & Lyman, 1968; Scully, 1990; Sykes & Matza, 1957)

Note: personality theory(Sigmund Freud) tend to lack empirical evidence as pointed out by (Stinson, Sales & Becker, 2008)

further reading/source:https://smart.ojp.gov/somapi/chapter-2-etiology-adult-sexual-offending

"Hope this helps"

Comment: Do you have studies that particularly deal with voluntary celibacy and abstinence too?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Can you please [provide full reference information](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2560/7604) for Personality Theories Seidman and colleagues (1994), Bowlby (1988), Cognitive Theories (Scott & Lyman, 1968; Scully, 1990; Sykes & Matza, 1957), personality theory (Sigmund Freud) and Stinson, Sales & Becker, (2008)? Non of these return anything relevant when searching Google Scholar

Comment: As for "sexual offender treatment programs" mentioned in your link, they are totally ineffective. (See https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/19112/7604)